# Replace file if and only if stdin differs from file contents

Tags: shell, files, pipe, file-copy, diff

I am looking for a program that takes a file name (e.g. as an argument), reads from `stdin` into a buffer, and compares this with the contents of the named file.

If the contents differ, the program (ideally atomically) overwrites the file with the contents of the input buffer.

Otherwise, it leaves the file unchanged - no write occurs, no change of last-modified timestamp, and without generating a temporary file.

Example Usage: `echo "test" | myprogram myfile.txt`

Does this program exist as a common Unix command line tool? Is there some nice way to achieve this tersely in the shell without a temporary file? (rsync do otherwise)

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash

TMP_FILE=/tmp/myprogram.$$.tmp
COMP_FILE="$1"

test -f "$COMP_FILE" && test -r "$COMP_FILE" && test -w "$COMP_FILE" || exit 2

cat >"$TMP_FILE"
cmp "$COMP_FILE" "$TMP_FILE" || cp "$TMP_FILE" "$COMP_FILE"
rm "$TMP_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not an existing tool that does what you want.
The following script `myprogram` should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

var="$(cat)"
md5_stdin=$(echo "$var" | md5sum | cut -d" " -f 1)
md5_file=$(md5sum myfile.txt | cut -d" " -f1)
[[ "$md5_stdin" != "$md5_file" ]] && echo "$var" > myfile.txt
```